# vb.net within an SQL statement I need to count an occurrence

Tags: sql, vb.net, select, odbc

In vb.net, I have a database of employee's and checks that I access using ODBC. I have created an SQL Select statement that summarizes different values based on if it's a certain tax Id, I also counts how many weeks each employee worked during the use selected date range (i.e. did the employee received a check). It all works great and is accurate. But I now need to determine with a yes or no if the employee received a check that feel during the week that was a 12th of the month with in the date range. I have no clue where to even start as I can't get any of my attempts at this to compile or run the code. There are two user prompts for starting and ending date for the date range, all weeks end on a Sunday. My current select statement that works correctly so far is here:

```
`SELECT tb1.Employee, SUM(CASE WHEN tb1.TaxID = 'SOC' THEN tb1.Taxable Else 0 END) " & _
"as txblSOC, SUM(CASE WHEN tb1.TaxID = 'MED' THEN tb1.Taxable Else 0 END) as txblMED, " & _
"SUM(CASE WHEN tb1.TaxID = 'FED' THEN tb1.Taxable ELSE 0 END) as txblFED, " & _
"COUNT(CASE WHEN tb1.CheckNumb > 0 Then tb1.PeriodEndDate END) as wks, " & _
"emp1.Name, emp1.SSN, emp1.Add1, emp1.Add2, emp1.City, emp1.State, " & _
"emp1.ZipCode FROM PRCHECKTAX tb1 " & _
"INNER JOIN PRCHECK tb2 ON tb1.Employee = tb2.Employee AND tb1.PeriodEndDate = " & _ 
"tb2.PeriodEndDate AND tb1.CheckNumb = tb2.CheckNumb " & _
"INNER JOIN PREMPLOYEE AS emp1 ON tb1.Employee = emp1.Employee " & _
"WHERE (tb1.TaxID = 'SOC' OR tb1.TaxID = 'MED' OR tb1.TaxID = 'FED') AND " & _
"tb1.Taxable <> 0 AND tb2.CheckDate BETWEEN  & sz1 & " AND " & sz2 & " " & _
"GROUP BY tb1.Employee, emp1.Name,"emp1.SSN, emp1.Add1, emp1.Add2, emp1.City, " & _ 
"emp1.State, emp1.ZipCode"`
```

Comment: That sounds as if you might want to Tag the `RDBMS` you are `ODBC`-connecting to because your question seems being more about the RDBMS Date handling capabilities rather than VB.Net abilities

Comment: Possible approaches I can suggest. 1) update your select query with group functions (Count, Sum etc).  2) leave query as is then using tools like Linq to query and summarise the result data set. 3) Make subsequent calls to DB for summary data

Comment: Hursey, yeah I had already worked out code to your #3, but the ODBC driver from the database provider is not well written and is only offered in 32 bit driver, so when I do multiple references to get the different parts of the query I need the length of time it takes to go back through the database become exponentially slower etc.  The users are getting frustrated as it literally takes an hour using multiple calls vs 10 minutes in one pass.

Comment: Would suggest then based on that comment, perhaps number 2).   Assuming this is being returned as a DataTable,  should be relatively simple to preform some Linq queries to get your required summary values

Comment: Perhaps you could have formatted your SQL code so it was easy for us to read.